# maven deployment of configuration information to tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

In my current development/deployment workflow I deploy my (Java/Spring) web apps to a remote tomcat containers by using the tomcat7 maven plugin.
This makes easy for me to simply deploy the new version of my app by invoking

> mvn tomcat7:deploy

My specific problem now is how to correctly handle configuration information: at the moment I keep configuration information (db connection info, passwords, etc.) in .properties files which are  packaged with my war and then deployed remotely to the container as described above. An improvement of this process is the use of maven profiles to include different versions of .properties for different target deploy environments.

The problem with this approach is that sentitive information (eg. passwords) are packaged with the war file, while I would prefer to have them somewhere else on the server, visible to the web app (e.g. as part of its classpath), but manageable independently (so as to allow a change in some config settings withouth having to rebuild/redeploy the app).

The only solution I've found so far for this implies the following steps:

1) do not include the .properties in the packaged war

2) deploy the war to the remote server with mvn tomcat7:deploy

3) *manually* copy the .properties on some server folders where they are accessible from the web app via classpath

In step 3) "manually" means not using maven-based mechanisms for this step. Can someone suggest me some mechanism through which both the packaged war and the configuration files can be separately deployed to a remote server (for instance some ?

Answer (score 0):

```
For example , you can do this :
1. Create module_config.zip with maven-assembly-plugin contains : *.properties
2. Deploy war with mvn tomcat7:deploy 
3. Start script to copy module_config > dir_deploy_application 
4. ReStart tomcat7
You can do it with (sh script) or (jenkins)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I was looking specifically for some mechanisms that allowed me to do everything (i.e. deploy both the packaged war and the .properties file) entirerly via maven.